# What are these three extra chars and why do they cause such a strange error?

Tags: bash, error-handling

Look at these two files:

- [File 1](https://github.com/erelsgl/hw1sb/blob/master/BasicCheck.sh)
- [File 2](https://github.com/erelsgl/hw1sb2/blob/master/BasicCheck.sh)

They look to me entirely identical, but File 1 has 41 bytes and File 2 has 44 bytes.

Now, I would not care about 3 extra chars, however, I think these chars are also responsible to a strange error: when I clone and run these files, File 1 runs OK while File 2 returns an error on line 3: "./BasicCheck.sh: line 3: cd: case0 : No such file or directory".

So: what are these extra chars? Why do they cause errors? And what should I do to fix these errors?

My guess is that they are newlines - perhaps File 1 has Linux-based newlines and File 2 has Windows-based newlines. Is it correct? And why should it cause such errors?

Comment: Don't make us chase links. Post the text here, and highlight the differences.

Comment: @glennjackman that's exactly the point - there are no visible differences. If I copy the text from both links, they will appear exactly the same and there will be no way to find out the difference. This is why I give the links to the original files.

Comment: Run both scripts through `od -c filename` and you'll be shown the exact characters in the files. If one script has DOS-style newlines (with a 3 line file, that would account for the extra 3 bytes) then I would have expected a different error message. Or specifically, the same error message, but "garbled".

Comment: Please also show exactly how you *invoke* these scripts.

Comment: If it's a newline issue then the directory you're trying to cd into looks like `$filename\r` with an extra invisible character. But I'd expect the error message to **start** with `: No such file or directory` because of the carriage return in the *middle* of the error message.

Comment: One file has lines terminated by cr/lf (dos mode), the other just by lf (unix mode). The extra chars are carriage returns / \r / CR / ascii 13.

Comment: @glennjackman the "od" tip was very useful - I did not know about it - it immediately showed the extra "\r"!

Comment: The `dos2unix` command is your friend to fix such files. You should investigate the settings for your editor to save files in "unix format".

Comment: When I download the two linked files I see two totally different HTML files. If you're going to link to external files, link _directly_ to the files in question; not web pages! Or better, as @glennjackman says, don't post links at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `file` command points out the issue:

```
% file file*
file1: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
file2: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators
```

The second script is in "DOS" format.  and so will not work as expected.  You can convert it with `dos2unix` and the results are now the same

```
% dos2unix file2
dos2unix: converting file file2 to Unix format ...

% ls -l file1 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 41 Mar 19 11:23 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 41 Mar 19 11:25 file2
```

When you try to use a DOS format file with Unix commands, there is a trailing control-M at the end of every line.  So a line such as

```
a=b
```

will really set `a` to b followed by control-M, shorthand `^M`:

```
a=b^M
```

Every command will be similarly impacted; eg a simple line with the two-character command `ls` would try to run the three-character command `ls<control-M>`, which doesn't exist.